# detect string-length on paste on maxlength-set input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a long shot, but I thought I might as well as ask. I have a text input with a `maxlength` of 100, is there anyway of detecting, on paste, if the user attempted to paste text with a string length greater than 100(before it was shortened automatically)? Thanks.

```
$('#limitedText').paste(function(){
   if($(this).val().length > 100) {
     //do somthing  
  } 
});

<input type = "text" id = "limitedText" maxlength = "100">
```

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the `maxlength` attribute and instead add an `onchange` listener to get the current value and then truncate to 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fiStrinLen(id)
{
    var st = id.value;
    var stLen = st.length;
    if(stLen>100)
    {
        alert("Before\n\n"+id.value)
        id.value = st.substring(0,99)
        alert("After\n\n"+id.value)
    }
}


'<input id="pasChar" type="text" name="testInput" oninput="fiStrinLen(this)" />'
```